# Magnetically separating H2 and O2 in a volume of gas

Tags: home-experiment, electrolysis, magnetism

I'm using a method of electrolysis where the anode and cathode are in close proximity (~0.7mm) and therefore the separate collection of H2 from the cathode is very difficult. Since O2 is paramagnetic and H2 is diamagnetic I was thinking I could use permanent magnets to separate the gases in a specially constructed bubbler.

Is it possible to calculate the required magnetic field strength necessary to perform this separation? If so, can you provide a formula or point me in the right direction where I can read about how to calculate this?

Comment: You would need a very low temperature and a very strong magnet.

Comment: [Relevant question](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/33994/1499)

Comment: That would be about as practical as making gold from mercury in particle accelerators.

Comment: @DHMO or thousands of steps in a cascade (like the processes used to concentrate uranium isotopes). Hardly cheap or practical even compared to fractional distillation of the liquefied gas.

Comment: All of your comments have been very helpful, and while DHMO's response is qualitatively correct, the relevant question referenced in #2 provided a formula that seems applicable to my situation. Thank you!