What is the effect of an applied magnetic field on crystal field splitting?
I was just learning about complex ions in my chemistry course. We further learnt about the factors that lead to the crystal field energy splitting of the d orbitals. One of which is orbital overlap (Source).
I further know that the shape of atomic orbitals change in an applied magnetic field due to the force felt by electron, a charged particle.
Hence, I thought if a magnetic field could alter the energy splitting of a complex ion.

See the https://chem.libretexts.org/Courses/Duke_University/CHEM_210D:_Modern_Applications_of_Chemistry/3:_Textbook-_Modern_Applications_of_Chemistry/10:_Coordination_Chemistry/10.12:_Magnetic_Behavior_of_Complex_Ions, for example. Consider that simple hydrogen is affected by magnetic field: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/142768/behavior-of-ortho-and-para-hydrogen-in-a-magnetic-field

Applied magnetic field would hardly do anything. Related: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/33994/could-a-magnet-pull-oxygen-out-of-the-air
